# Ionic 3 login issue (it wont load after authService)

Tags: node.js, typescript, ionic3

The `if` statement works just fine but it won't load through the

```
this.authService.postData(this.userData,"login").then((result)
```

I've tried to look through online and it doesn't seem like there is a solution for me.

```
if(this.userData.email && this.userData.password){
      this.authService.postData(this.userData, "login").then((result) =>{
        this.responseData = result;
        if(this.responseData.error){
           this.showToast(this.responseData.error.text, 'bottom');
        }else{
          if(this.responseData.userData){
            localStorage.setItem('userData',JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
            const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
            this.userDetails = data.userData; 
            this.menu.enable(true);
            this.reloadmenu(this.userDetails.role);
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
          }else{
            this.presentPrompt("Email or password not valid");
          }
        }
      }, (err) => {
        // connection failed
      });
    }
```

This is my PHP side

```js
function login() {
    
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody());
    
    try {
        
        $userData = ''; 
  require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';
  $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
  global $wpdb;
  $sql = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_USER." WHERE user_login LIKE '%".$data->email."%'");

  if(!empty($sql)){
   $password_hashed = $sql->user_pass;
   if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword($data->password, $password_hashed)){
      $array = json_decode(json_encode($sql), true);
      $array['password'] = $data->password;
      if($sql->user_role=='Admin' || $sql->user_role=='Administrator') {
     $array['role'] = 'developer';
    }else if($sql->user_role=='Author' || $sql->user_role=='Maincon') {
     $array['role'] = 'vendor';
    }
      $userData = json_encode($array);
      echo '{"userData": ' .$userData . '}';
   } else {
      echo '{"error":{"text":"Bad request wrong email or password!"}}';
   }
  }else{
    echo '{"error":{"text":"Bad request user not exist!"}}';
  }
           
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow ! Do you have any errors in your Console ? ( F12 ).

Comment: Hi, it doesn't show any error